# Opening an Access database file using Jackcess

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, jackcess

I am using the Jackcess API to copy my database to into a file. I successfully establish a connection to my database but when I try to open the database I get a null pointer exception.

My code

```
File tempTarget=File.createTempFile("eap-mirror", "eap");     
String conString = EaDbStringParser.eaDbStringToJdbc(sourceString);
this.source=DriverManager.getConnection(conString);
this.source.setReadOnly(true);
try {
    FileUtils.copyFile(new File(templateFileString), tempTarget);
    System.out.println("file copied");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

this.target=Database.open(tempTarget,false,false); //Cannot run this line
```

I am not able to run Database.open method and hence the target is null which throws the exception.

Anyone having any idea what I am doing wrong or what is required here?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jackcess DatabaseBuilder.open fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29844258/jackcess-databasebuilder-open-fails)

Answer (score 1):

`com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.Database` has no `.open` method (ref: [here](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/healthmarketscience/jackcess/Database.html)). To open a database file in Jackcess we use `DatabaseBuilder.open`, as in

```java
this.target = DatabaseBuilder.open(tempTarget);
```

Edit:

I see from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29844258/2144390) that you are trying to use a rather old 1.x version of Jackcess (1.2.6) that did offer an .open method for a Database object. You really should consider using a more current 2.x version of Jackcess.

Comment: but in eclipse it provides me the Database.open() method and imported com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.Database;

Comment: There is one maven project in my workspace if I call this method from the maven project it works and if I call it from a plugin project its not working

Comment: Then that must be some other `Database` object, not the `com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.Database` interface.

Comment: I don't think so because If I remove the import the Database is no more recognized