# Jackcess DatabaseBuilder.open fails

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, jackcess

I am using Jackcess API in my Eclipse plugin project. I added  `jackcess-2.1.0.jar` file under *resources/lib*. I included the jar under my Binary build and in `build.properties`. I successfully make a connection using connection string but my `DatabaseBuilder.open()` call is not executing. My code is

```
 public void run() {
    try {
        File tempTarget = File.createTempFile("eap-mirror", "eap");
        try {
            this.source = DriverManager.getConnection(EaDbStringParser.eaDbStringToJdbc(sourceString));
            this.source.setReadOnly(true);

            try {
                FileUtils.copyFile(new File(templateFileString), tempTarget);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Changes
            try {
                this.target = DatabaseBuilder.open(tempTarget);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Collection<String> tables = selectTables(source);
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for (String tableName : tables) {
                long tTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                Table table = target.getTable(tableName);
                System.out.print("Mirroring table " + tableName + "...");
                table.setOverrideAutonumber(true);

                copyTable(table, source, target);
                System.out.println(" took "+ (System.currentTimeMillis() - tTime));
            }
            System.out.println("Done. Overall time: "+ (System.currentTimeMillis() - time));
            System.out.println("done");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

          // More Code here

  } catch (IOException e1) {

    }
}
```

When I run the class in debug mode and I reach `DatabaseBuilder.open` call it fails.

Here is my project structure:

[image: My project structure]

Can anyone tell me the possible reason for it ?

Comment: An exception is being thrown and you're swallowing it?

Comment: No exception is thrown I am catching the exceptions but no exception is thrown I think

Comment: Jackcess 1.2.6 is a very old version. Is there a particular reason why you are not using the [current version](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jackcess/files/latest/download?source=files)?

Comment: There is no particular reason actually it was implemented as long ago but it works in web environment from a maven project it works but now I want to integrate it in an rcp application and there its not working

Comment: You really should use a current (2.x) version of Jackcess if at all possible.

Comment: I tried 2.1.0 now and at this line this.target = DatabaseBuilder.open(tempTarget); still it jumps to the finally block

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the revised code.

Comment: check the updated code and my project structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.open` method of `DatabaseBuilder` expects to open an existing well-formed Access database file. The `.createTempFile` method of `java.io.File` creates a 0-byte file. So, the code

```java
File dbFile;
try {
    dbFile = File.createTempFile("eap-mirror", "eap");
    try (Database db = DatabaseBuilder.open(dbFile)) {
        System.out.println(db.getFileFormat());
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(System.out);
} finally {
    System.out.println("Finally...");
}
```

will cause Jackcess to throw

> java.io.IOException: Empty database file

when it tries to do `DatabaseBuilder.open(dbFile)`.

Instead, you should `DatabaseBuilder.create` to convert the 0-byte file into a real Access database file like this

```java
File dbFile;
try {
    dbFile = File.createTempFile("eap-mirror", ".accdb");
    dbFile.deleteOnExit();
    try (Database db = DatabaseBuilder.create(Database.FileFormat.V2010, dbFile)) {
        System.out.println(db.getFileFormat());
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(System.out);
} finally {
    System.out.println("Finally...");
}
```